# How can I pass a Python Dictionary as an argument when calling VBScript in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, vbscript, arguments

Lets say we have some python dictionary and we have a VBScript. We are going to call the script in python and pass the dictionary as an argument like this:

```
import subprocess

dict = {}
dict ["x61"] = "P11"
dict ["x62"] = "P22"
dict ["x63"] = "P33"

subprocess.call(['cscript.exe', 'H:\\public\\vbscript.vbs', dict])
```

In the VBScript I am trying to assign the dictionary like this:

```
Dim dict
dict = WScript.Arguments(0)
```

The (error) output that I get in the terminal is:

```
required: 'x61x63x62'
```

May be because I am looping and trying to access all items in the dict:

```
dict.Item(some_variable)
```

Shall I serialize the dict object and how can I do it?

Comment: I suspect that `call`'s first argument can only contain strings. I suggest serializing the dictionary in a way that VB can decode later. Maybe Json?

Comment: Yeah, I think the solution will be something in that direction..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass objects thru the command line; the arguments need to be strings. So call the .vbs with a string representation of dict and parse the parameter in the .vbs. To get you started:

.py:

```
import subprocess

dict = {}
dict ["x61"] = "P11"
dict ["x62"] = "P22"
dict ["x63"] = "P33"

sdict = str(dict)

subprocess.call(['cscript.exe', '../vbs/25427813.vbs', sdict])
```

.vbs:

```
Option Explicit

Function dict(s)
  WScript.Echo "***", s
  Dim tmp
  Set tmp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
  r.Global = True
  r.Pattern = "'([^']+)': '?([^']+)'?"
  Dim m
  For Each m In r.Execute(s)
      tmp(m.SubMatches(0)) = m.SubMatches(1)
  Next
  Set dict = tmp
End Function

WScript.Echo dict(WScript.Arguments(0))("x62")
```

output:

```
python 25427813.py
*** {'x61': 'P11', 'x63': 'P33', 'x62': 'P22'}
P22
```

Instead of 'rolling your own' you could use an established format, e.g. JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really got me to the solution. Everything is working as expected now!